# wf2123 nettis usb wifi adapter don't compile

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, compiling, make

StackExchange! I have ubuntu 22.04 lts and a nettis wf2123 usb wifi adapter. I download driver from the nettis website but when i run sudo sh ./install.sh i get this error:

```
home/dmitriykalshnikov/Downloads/RTL8192EU_WF2123_WF2122/RTL8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696_BTCOEX20160412-0042.20160510/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/dmitriykalshnikov/Downloads/RTL8192EU_WF2123_WF2122/RTL8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696_BTCOEX20160412-0042.20160510/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/include/osdep_service_linux.h:273:15: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  273 |         ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |               ^~
/home/dmitriykalshnikov/Downloads/RTL8192EU_WF2123_WF2122/RTL8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696_BTCOEX20160412-0042.20160510/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/include/osdep_service_linux.h:274:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  274 |         init_timer(ptimer);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
      |         _init_timer
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:297: /home/dmitriykalshnikov/Downloads/RTL8192EU_WF2123_WF2122/RTL8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696_BTCOEX20160412-0042.20160510/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1907: /home/dmitriykalshnikov/Downloads/RTL8192EU_WF2123_WF2122/RTL8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696_BTCOEX20160412-0042.20160510/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-71-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1686: modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

please help me install this driver!

ps: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
driver from here isn't work for me -- system after final reboot doesn't see my adapter

Comment: __1__ `sudo bash ...` might be better.  __2__ You're missing some `#include` files. `sudo apt install build-essential` should pick them up.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: the build-essential package is installed on my system (the lastest version), sudo bash ... gave me the same output as sudo sh, lsusb gave me this:

Comment: Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0c45:5004 Microdia Redragon Mitra RGB Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0c45:6340 Microdia Camera
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek 8812AU/8821AU 802.11ac WLAN Adapter [USB Wireless Dual-Band Adapter 2.4/5Ghz]

Answer (score 0):

> Device 005: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek
> 8812AU/8821AU 802.11ac WLAN Adapter [USB Wireless Dual-Band Adapter
> 2.4/5Ghz]

The correct driver for your device is 88XXau. With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

You should be all set.

Comment: When i have installed this driver, it brake my system

Comment: after reboot my system give me black screen

Comment: rebooting with older kernel save my ubuntu

Comment: Please show us in an edit to your question: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: [sudo] password for dmitriykalshnikov: 
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/455.45.01/source/dkms.conf does not exist.